# Multiple screens gets not detected

Tags: lubuntu, hdmi, 17.04, xrandr, vga

I have two screens and getting both detected is some kind of luck.

My computer has 1 VGA out, 2 DP out, and 1 HDMI out. However I have only 2 VGA cables and an HDMI to VGA adapter. The pure VGA works fine, however the HDMI out (with adapter) sometimes stops working after a reboot. But I can not precisely reproduce, when it stops.

This is what xrandr says witch does not make any sense to m. Why does it say that DP-3 is connected when it just isn't.

```
$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 8192 x 8192
HDMI-1 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
   1280x1024     60.02*+  75.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

I use Lubuntu 17.04.

Comment: what graphics driver are you using? nouveau doesn't really support multiple screens, so you should try to use proprietary drivers

Comment: Intel drivers. Sorry, i forgot to mark the problem as solved, but it solved itself so I don't konw how. :(

Comment: Should I flag this question as Cannot Reproduce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved itself so I don't know how. :(